# How can I make a ListItem(in React) in the bottom left corner, in the following example?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import MuiAppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import SchoolIcon from '@mui/icons-material/School';
import ClassIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Class';

const drawerWidth = 240;
const icons = [<HomeIcon/>, <ClassIcon/>,<SchoolIcon/>]

const openedMixin = (theme) => ({
  width: drawerWidth,
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
});

const closedMixin = (theme) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  overflowX: 'hidden',
  width: `calc(${theme.spacing(7)} + 1px)`,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    width: `calc(${theme.spacing(8)} + 1px)`,
  },
});

const DrawerHeader = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    ...(open && {
      ...openedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': openedMixin(theme),
    }),
    ...(!open && {
      ...closedMixin(theme),
      '& .MuiDrawer-paper': closedMixin(theme),
    }),
  }),
);

export default function MiniDrawer({children}) {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{
              marginRight: 5,
              ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
            }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            NOPF
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
        <DrawerHeader>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <ChevronRightIcon /> : <ChevronLeftIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {['Home', 'Klasse', 'Schule'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block' }}>
              <ListItemButton
                sx={{
                  minHeight: 48,
                  justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                  px: 2.5,
                }}
              >
                <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
                >
                  {icons[index]}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}

          <ListItem disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block', position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0 }}>
            <ListItemButton
              sx={{
                minHeight: 48,
                justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                px: 2.5,
              }}
            >
              <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
              >
                <HomeIcon/>
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={'Profil'} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>

        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
        <DrawerHeader />
        {children}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This is my code. It is a Drawer (slightly modified by me) from the MaterialUI Website(https://next.mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#anchor). Important is only the return in the MiniDrawer function (I wanted to provide you with the complete code so you can maybe understand the whole thing). I wanted to create an other ListItem but this one should be in the bottom left corner, not like the others on the top left, like you see in this picture:
[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uPwA.png)

But as you can see, the moment I hover anywhere on the height of the ListItem I can click it (this should not be possible). That is how it should be:

[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxbwr.png)

The first thing I tried, as you can see in the first line of the code, is to manually declare the maxWidth, but this is not a good solution because when the device width is another (for example: Iphone, Ipad, ...) the max width changes too.

```
 <ListItem disablePadding sx={{ display: 'block', position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0, maxWidth: open ? 256 : 64 }}>
            <ListItemButton
              sx={{
                minHeight: 48,
                justifyContent: open ? 'initial' : 'center',
                px: 2.5,
              }}
            >
              <ListItemIcon
                  sx={{
                    minWidth: 0,
                    mr: open ? 3 : 'auto',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                  }}
              >
                <HomeIcon/>
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={'Profil'} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
```